# LightSwitch - List detail screen with several one to many to the same child entity

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I have multiple one to many relationship on the same child entity:

Let's say that I have one Product entitiy and one Brand entity each of these have 1:N relationship with a media entity (use to reference image video ect...), this makes the table Media to have two FK columns on Product & Brand, if the first is set the other one sould be null
These entities are exposed with Odata.

In LS when I create a listDetail screen for the brand entity, everything is ok, I can add the media grid to see what medias are related to my brand.

But I can not add media, the button is greyed.

When I try to override the Add button on the media grid using my own Modalwindows (based on Yann Durand's code) I get an error : "Adding a new element on this collection is not authorized" does it  mean that the VisualCollection Medias is readonly ?

I suspect that it could be related to the fact that there are several FK on the media table.

Is my design flawed or is it someting LS cannot handle out of the box ?

Thank for your help

Axel